# Sorting lists of different classes

Tags: c#, list, sorting, generics

I wonder if I can create a more generic approach to a problem I have with sorting different lists currently in my C# project.

I have ClassA which contains an integer value (age) that I want to use for sorting later.
And I have ClassB which also contains an integer value (id) that I want to use for sorting.

So currently I'm using the C# List.Sort function for that, which takes as comparer function which needs the class which should be compared:

```
List<ClassA> pupils;
pupils.Sort(compareAge);
```

where compareAge is:

```
 int compareAge(ClassA pupilOne, ClassB pupilTwo)
 {
    return pupilOne.Age.CompareTo(pupilTwo.Age);
 }
```

Works nicely, but now I want to use the same function for ClassB, but it should ofcourse take ClassB and take the Id instead of the age. Something like:

```
List<ClassB> classRooms;
SortByInteger<List<ClassB>(classRooms, id);

List<T> compareByInt<T>(T listToSort, PropertyInfo property)
{
    // ? is this possible?
}
```

One Note: as I'm going to use the code on mobile too, I try to avoid LINQ as much as I can. So can I do it in any way with the build in C# functions or how can I do it on my own?

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could at least do

```
List<ClassA> pupils;
pupils.Sort((a,b) => a.Age.CompareTo(b.Age));

List<ClassB> classRooms;
classRooms.Sort((a,b) => a.Id.CompareTo(b.Id));
```

which saves you the function declaration.

For more convenience add your own wrapper for calling `Sort`:

```
static class Tools
{
    static public void SortBy<T,TKey>(this List<T> list, Func<T,TKey> sel) {
        list.Sort((a,b) => Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(sel(a), sel(b)));
    } 
}
```

Then you can write:

```
List<ClassA> pupils;
pupils.SortBy(a => a.Age);

List<ClassB> classRooms;
classRooms.SortBy(a => a.Id);
```

Comment: re your edit - that would be more correct as `=> Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(sel(a), sel(b))`

Comment: Your `SortBy` either need to constrain `Key` to `IComparable` or you'll need to get the default comparer for that type.  You're also missing a parenthesis at the end of the `Sort` call.

Comment: @MarcGravell Not only more correct, it wouldn't compile without it.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks! My brain based compiler is not optimal yet :)

Answer (score 0):

How about you define an interface:

```
public interface IPupil
{
  int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and then use it in your comparison function like this:

```
   int compareAge(IPupil pupilOne, IPupil pupilTwo)
   {
      return pupilOne.Age.CompareTo(pupilTwo.Age);
   }
```

Comment: This would be a solution for this problem, but I would have to implement more interfaces if I come to the same problem if I want to compare against other value types (DateTime, float,....).